# How do i pass authorized user from one application to another running in same server?

Tags: asp.net, authorization, session-cookies

Architecture of my application is something like this.I have a application which is hub for many other applications which allows user to pass credentials. After credentials are checked, Hub application presents one or more applications which the user is allowed to use. If user has only one application it redirects directly to the application. How do i maintain the authorized state of the user passed in hub application and access them again in the children application?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "one way" to do this. But one way to do this is to provide a Javascript Web Token (JWT) back to the client if they log in successfully. The server can then know,  authentically, who the user is that made the request if the client provides the JWT as a request header (typically "Authorization: Bearer JWT- goes-here). You can keep the JWT in some kind of local storage like IndexDB to share between applications (assuming same domain URL) and delete it if the user logs out.

Also, in case it's not obvious, definitely use HTTPS. There is no excuse not to in 2019, with the existence of LetsEncrypt.

if you are using Express.js use express-jwt and jsonwebtoken packages to accomplish this scheme.

Comment: Not sure how you can share data between two different applications (domains) on the client side for security reasons... you might be able to share a cookie somehow, but I'm not sure. If you mount the applications in subfolders of the same domain,  they can trivially share an IndexDB in the browser,  since it doesn't know they are different apps.

Comment: URLs are not the same. What i am doing right now is once identify the authorization of the user, I am redirecting the user to the another application's index action (which is also asp.net mvc app ). Since this application does not have any idea of authorization for the user, i have to check again which I feel like overhead and does not look seamless. Authorization of the user persist in the application database  not in the Hub (parent application db). So right now i have to make call to the db to check authenticated user has authorization to access the application or not.